# Replacing a branch solution with a label under TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When a solution is published in production, usually we continue to develop in the same solution for the next release. But sometimes, the production version contains a bug and need to be corrected asap (before the next release). The solution to this problem may be the use of branching under TFS (with merging when needed from A to B or B to A it depends...).

An example of implementation is showed here: http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/simple-branching-strategies-for-team-foundation-server

**My question**: I wonder if we can easily replace the branching solution with a label solution. If so, how? If not, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use branches, in addition to the link you posted you should also check out the [TFS ALM Rangers branching guidance](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Why not use labels?

1. Branching is designed to support exactly the scenario you describe, it is the standard way of dealing with parallel development.
2. In TFS Labels are not immutable, i.e. they can be changed after they have been created.
3. Labels do not have a history, this means that if someone changes a label you do not know who, why or when. Therefore you cannot "trust" a label to identify the same code it did when you created it.